# only one label select is showing in html

Tags: html, css

I am having two `label select` in a `div` but only one is showing. Is there anything wrong with this ?

```
<div id="ElementDetails"> 
    <label id = "ElementOne">Element_1 :</label>
    <select id="elementOptionOne">
    <label id = "ElementTwo">css Selector :</label>
    <select id="elementOptionTwo">
</div>
```

Comment: yes you have to close your select element

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/

Comment: Why a downvote ? i was facing this since half hour ! Is there something wrong in asking this ?

Comment: In stack overflow every one interested to make down vote. Check before you post simple questions. Learn well. Good luck

Comment: Thanks @RemyaR i will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 5):

Your selects elements are not closed. You need to close them before using an other label :

```html
<div id="ElementDetails">
  <label id="ElementOne">Element_1 :</label>
  <select id="elementOptionOne">
  </select>
  <label id="ElementTwo">css Selector :</label>
  <select id="elementOptionTwo">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed it as i am new to this. @Magicprog.fr